# MX records for a domain with a CNAME

Tags: smtp, sendmail

Given something like this:

```
xxx.net.            CNAME    surrogate-xxx.net.
www.xxx.net.        CNAME    surrogate-xxx.net.
mail.xxx.net.       A        1.2.3.4
xxx.net.            MX       mail.xxx.net.

surrogate-xxx.net.  A        4.3.2.1
```

Should mail for xxx.net go to 1.2.3.4, as directed by the MX record, or to 4.3.2.1, as directed by the A record to which the CNAME points.

Comment: You probably have messed up the dots in your example - it looks like it should be xxx.net. (note the trailing dot).

Comment: Most dns servers will not load this zone, as 'xxx.net' has "CNAME and other data' - namely the SOA, so it most likey won't get served.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the zone as noted here is considered a bad practice. Defining a CNAME for the label xxx.net just "remaps" all RRs of xxx.net. to surrogate-xxx.net. **including** the MX record. Defining the MX RR for xxx.net. is asking for trouble. [RFC-1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html) has a clear statement on this topic:

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
>   this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
>   be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be used
>   without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

[Further reading here](http://email-museum.com/2008/09/08/why-you-shouldnt-mix-cname-and-mx/).

Answer (score -2):

Mail will flow to `mail.xxx.net` in that scenario.

Mail will flow to whatever the MX record(s) points to.

Now, if your MX record points to `mail.xxx.net` and `mail.xxx.net` points via CNAME to `surrogate-mail.xxx.net`, mail will flow to `surrogate-mail.xxx.net`.  Your MX record points to an endpoint - how you define that endpoint - A record, CNAME, etc. is up to you.